# Components for smartwatch

Tags: arduino, diy

I am relatively new to the smartwatch manufacturing process and I am not hardware engineer. I have seen few videos on DIY smartwatch. Following is what I have learned so far:

1. We need to manufacture the PCB by uploading the Geber file.
2. Solder the components to PCB.
3. I need the Arduino Bluetooth module to transfer the data from watch to the phone.
4. Motion sensors (gyroscope and accelerometer) to track hand movements.

The goal is to make a simple band that can track movements of my hand and send the data to cellphone.

My questions are:

1. Any suggestions on the specific components (motion sensors and battery) which I should buy to achieve the goal.
2. Is using cellular data and sending the data to the cloud better than using the Bluetooth. What can be the caveats, if any?

Comment: Welcome :-) I know this isn't answering your question, but you are missing at least 4 steps before your current list actually starts, so you might be underestimating the difficulties you could encounter e.g. (-3) Design hardware. (-2) Write software. (-1) Debug the combined system of hw & sw. (0) Layout the PCB. (Each of those steps can be sub-divided too). Also, your step 3 of using an Arduino Bluetooth module will make a bulky watch. Other Bluetooth options exist. Given that you aren't a hardware engineer, this might not be the best choice as a first project, but good luck anyway!

Comment: #user261789, Welcome and nice to meet you. Ah, let me see. me newbie first thing first is go ask Lady Ada what she recommends. Her newbie tutorial is always most  friendly, and everything, both hardware, and software is open source. You can always download for free the CAD PCB designs files etc. Ref (1) Adafruit GEMMA M0 - Miniature wearable electronic platform US$10.
(a) https://www.adafruit.com/product/3501,
(b) https://www.adafruit.com/product/3501#description,
/ to continue, ...

Comment: (c) https://www.adafruit.com/product/3501#technical-details,
(d) https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-gemma-m0/downloads,
(e) https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-Gemma-M0-PCB. Have a nice watch, cheers.

Comment: I suggest making something bigger than a watch for your first project, just because it is easier to experiment with bigger modules (e.g. you won't need a custom PCB). Maybe you can make an arduino-sized box, which you can hold in your hands. This is a prototype. Then, you will understand a lot more about the electronics, and you can make another one which is watch-sized.

Answer (score 2):

This is a great idea for a project, but as others have pointed out, you've skipped some crucial steps. Here are the steps I'd follow:

1. Describe in simple terms what the user will experience, or what problem they can solve, using your invention. (Congrats, you've done this already!)
2. Create a block diagram of the system. You've done this partially, you know you want a wireless system, with motion sensors and a battery, that can connect to a smartphone, but you're wondering whether to use Bluetooth or WiFi. I'll help you there: use Bluetooth Low Energy (4.x or 5.x) because it takes less power, and you only have room for a tiny battery in a wrist-wearable.
3. Build a "WORKS LIKE" prototype. This has the desired electrical design, but need not be wearable; in fact, it's usually sprawled out on your workbench. Obtain ready-made PCBs with the components you need (from Adafruit, Sparkfun, SeeedStudio). Hook things up, write the firmware, and try to get it working. You'll end up changing connections, substituting parts, and you'll be glad you didn't rush to build your own PCB.
4. Build a "LOOKS LIKE" prototype. This has the desired mechanical shape, but may have no electronics at all. This lets you confirm that your design is actually wearable.
5. Now that you've verified your electrical design and your mechanical concept, you can work on designing your custom PCB, ordering chips instead of ready-made modules, and fitting it all into your case.
6. If you succeed, and even if you fail, you will have extracted the maximum amount of learning from your project. And that's the point!